# H265 support with Mediasource?

Tags: media-source, hevc

I'm using the MediaSource in browsers to play H264 streams. This works very stable and good.

Now I just received a new device which produces H265 (hevc), and I stucked here.

I need to add the mimetype to addSourceBuffer, which in my case seems **hev1.1.2.L153**.

This is not supported by any browsers on my notebook.

From 2018 I found a forum post on [Dash.js](https://github.com/Dash-Industry-Forum/dash.js/issues/2385) quoting:

> I think Dash.js doesn't support any kind of HEVC. This maybe be confined to MediaSource, which doesn't support HEVC at present.

**My question: does MediaSource support any HEVC currently, or it is still stuck with H264?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question: does MediaSource support any HEVC currently, or it is
> still stuck with H264?

Depends on the browser, Edge may support it in some cases (hardware support), as well as safari, but Chrome (which is the majority of the market) will never support it due to h.265 outrages licensing costs.

Comment: Edge is based on Chromium, no?

Comment: Only the html renderer. The media stack is completely different