# Playing Audio, Video from a Proprietary Stream in a Web Browser

Tags: javascript, web, audio, video, h.264

I'd like to write a minimal, web-based audio/video player for a proprietary stream format.

I have a native iOS/tvOS app that accomplishes this by parsing the stream and taking the media format information, frame data and timing information and passing it to a decoder, and then displaying each frame (or passing the audio to a player). The video is always either H.264 or H.265. The audio is typically AAC or one of several other common codecs.

Is there a way to decode and display video frames in a web browser? Similarly, can I pass audio samples to a decoder and a player?

Asked another way, I'm looking for the web-based equivalent to VideoToolbox [1], AVSampleBufferDisplayLayer [2], AudioToolbox [3].

[1] https://developer.apple.com/documentation/videotoolbox

[2] https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avsamplebufferdisplaylayer

[3] https://developer.apple.com/documentation/audiotoolbox

Comment: _"Is there a way to decode and display video frames in a web browser?"_ Yes, just use MediaSource Extensions API. This allows you to feed H264 bytes, contained in Fragmented MP4 (or ISOBMFF) format to the decoder. You can also send AAC (in M4A) or PCM to the decoder, which is the HTML5 `<video>` tag. For wrapping the H264 samples as Frag-MP4  there is a library called Mux.JS. To get bytes you simply read the stream into a Buffer Array.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The only caveat I've discovered so far is that it seems that Chrome won't work with H.265, and that's not a deal-killer by any means. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63946746/h265-support-with-mediasource

Comment: Yeah, the Safari browser on Apple devices is the only one guaranteed to play H.265 via website... Basically consider web codecs as being H.264, VP 8 or 9 and OGV. With H.264 being the most supported by most browsers.